# How do I specify (1) an order and (2) a meaningful string representation for users in my Django application?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a Django application with users. I have a model called "Course" with a foreign key called "teacher" to the default User model that Django provides:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    ...
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='courses_taught')
```

When I create a model form to edit information for individual courses, the possible users for the teacher field appear in this long select menu of user names.

[image]

These users are ordered by ID, which is of meager use to me. How can I

1. order these users by their last names?
2. change the string representation of the User class to be "Firstname Lastname (username)" instead of "username"?

Comment: Changing the string representations of users, by the way, is my higher priority of the two.

Answer (score 0):

Firsty, the order. You can define a default order of model using the [nested `Meta` class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/). Check the [ordering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering) section.

Secondly, representation. You have to define a `__str__()`/`__unicode__()` methods for your model. They should return a string which represents an object. You can see an example in documentation. BUT, since `User` is a model from an outer module it may be hard to do it in that way.

You probably can:

- monkey-patch the `User` model meta class during app initialization OR
- subclass the `User` model, add `Meta` to the subclass and use it in place of the `User` OR
- write a custom field / form template which uses objects attributes instead of calling `str()`

it all depends on the current case

Answer (score 0):

## Abstract

If you're only dealing with the admin, it's better not to tinker with the `User` model itself, as subclassing `User` can be a pain down the road (especially when / if other developpers are going to work on your project), but use the admin's customization options.

## Solution

To solve your issue in the admin, you could use the `ModelAdmin` option `raw_id_fields`.

This will replace the `<select>` input with a widget that you can click to be redirected to your `User` admin and choose your user from.

From there, it's trivial to customize your `User` admin so that it:

- Displays your users in a relevant order (`ModelAdmin.ordering`)
- Displays the fields you're interest in (`ModelAdmin.list_display`)

Just remember than when you're registering your `User` admin, you need to use:

```
admin.site.unregister(User) #This!
admin.site.register(User, MyCustomUserAdmin)
```

## Alternate solution

Alternatively, you can always use `ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides`, which is more powerful but more complicated.

## Reference

You should look into the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/) for details on how to use those attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by customizing form field, here the `forms.ModelChoiceField`

```
 class CustomizedModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         # change default ordering
         super(CustomizedModelChoiceField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         self.queryset = self.queryset.order_by('last_name')

     def label_from_instance(self, obj):
         # change representation per item
         return u'{obj.first_name} {obj.last_name} ({obj.username})'.format(obj=obj)
```

Then use it in your form to replace default `ModelChoiceField`.

In Django Admin, it looks like

```
class CourseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):    
     def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
         if db_field.name == 'teacher':
             kwargs['form_class'] = CustomizedModelChoiceField
         return super(CourseAdmin, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)
```